# How to toggle icons and class name and click function on click

Tags: jquery

I've searched this answer for 6 hours but couldn't find. Sorry if it is duplicate.

I'm rookie at Jquery.

I want to change star color, div's class name and of course execute new class' process in jquery.

**Here is my html code:**

```
<div class="fav" haberid="10" habertype="bulunan"><img class="hav" src="http://myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav1.gif" border="0" id="10"/></div>
```

**This is my jquery code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.fav').click(function(){
         var haberid = $(this).attr('haberid');
         var habertype = $(this).attr('habertype');
         var fav = "fav";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/pages/islem/fav.php",
            data: {id: haberid, type: habertype, fav: fav}, 
            success:function(data){
            }
        });    
        $(this).html( "<img class=\"hav\" src=\"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav2.gif\" />");
        $(this).attr('class','fav2');
     });



     $('.fav2').click(function(){
         var haberid = $(this).attr('haberid');
         var habertype = $(this).attr('habertype'); 
         var fav = "fav2";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/pages/islem/fav.php",
            data: {id: haberid, type: habertype, fav: fav}, 
            success:function(data){
            }
        });    
        $(this).html( "<img class=\"hav\" src=\"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav1.gif\" />");
        $(this).attr('class','fav2');
     });
 });
```

When i first click, it changes from fav1.gif to fav2.gif and class name from "fav" to "fav2" and $.ajax post works.

But it does not work back (toogle) when i click new fav2.gif. No icon change, no class change, no ajax post.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('[class*=fav]').click(function(){
     var haberid = $(this).attr('haberid');
     var habertype = $(this).attr('habertype');
     var fav = $(this).hasClass('fav') ? 'fav2' : 'fav';
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/pages/islem/fav.php",
        data: {id: haberid, type: habertype, fav: fav}, 
        success:function(data){}
    });    
    $(this).html( "<img class='" + fav + "' src='http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/" + fav + ".gif' />");
    $(this).attr('class',fav);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not apply `click` listener on the same div twice to get toggle effect. Just apply or remove a particular class to identify current toggle state.

**EDIT:**

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vRCj5/1)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fav" haberid="10" habertype="bulunan">
    <img class="hav" src="http://myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav1.gif" border="0" id="10" />
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fav').click(function () {
        var haberid = $(this).attr('haberid');
        var habertype = $(this).attr('habertype');

        if ($(this).hasClass("fav")) {
            var fav = "fav";

            $(this).html("<img class=\"hav\" src=\"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav2.gif\" />");
            $(this).attr('class', 'fav2');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("fav2")) {
            var fav = "fav2";
            $(this).html("<img class=\"hav\" src=\"http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/media/photos/fav1.gif\" />");
            $(this).attr('class', 'fav');
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.myurl.com/robot_yeni/inc/pages/islem/fav.php",
            data: {
                id: haberid,
                type: habertype,
                fav: fav
            },
            success: function (data) {}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, it works on demo. but does not work on my job. i have no class as "fav1". renamed it as "fav". but still doesn't work.

Comment: [**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vRCj5/1) Also updated the answer with optimized code.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer too. I will study on this to learn essentials.

Thank you very much.